# How to convert values from input radio in boolean in React Hook Form?

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I have input radio in React Hook Form and I try to use it as real boolean, instead of string.

I know that RHF have `valueAsNumber` to convert it as number. I thought that `setValueAs` was a generic way to allow any conversion but I can't make it work.

[Code Sanbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/convert-in-boolean-with-rhf-and-zod-5spbub)

```
const schema = z.object({
  name: z.string().min(4, { message: "4 caractères minimum pour le name" }),
  developer: z.boolean() // A real boolean is expected here
});

export default function App() {
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    watch,
    formState: { errors }
  } = useForm({
    resolver: zodResolver(schema),
    defaultValues: {
      name: "John",
      developer: false // default as boolean
    }
  });

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)} noValidate>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Name" {...register("name")} />

      <p>
        Is developer ?&nbsp;
        <label>
          Oui
          <input
            {...register("developer", {
              setValueAs: (val) => true // Try to make it as a real boolean but doesn't work
            })}
            type="radio"
            value={true}
          />
        </label>
        <label>
          Non
          <input
            {...register("developer", {
              setValueAs: (val) => false
            })}
            type="radio"
            value={false}
          />
        </label>
      </p>

      <input type="submit" />

    </form>
  );
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: 'use it as real boolean, instead of string' you need to specify your question.

Comment: How to be clearer? I don't want that the value of input to be saved as a string, as native inputs do. I want to preserve the nature of the data wich is a real boolean. Not "true" and "false". This is a question of web api and React Hook Form, not a JS one.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I find out how to get a boolean from a radio input in RHF.

The solution with setValueAs, as I tried before, only works for text input (like type="text" or type="number"). For radio button, even if the value is a string, it doesn't work.

So it can be solved by using a Controller component.

[Code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/convert-in-boolean-with-rhf-and-zod-solved-1s3sf7?file=/src/App.js)

```
function MyBooleanInput({ control, name }) {
  return (
    <Controller
      control={control}
      name={name}
      render={({ field: { onChange, onBlur, value, ref } }) => (
        <>
          <label>
            Oui
            <input
              type="radio"
              onBlur={onBlur} // notify when input is touched
              onChange={() => onChange(true)} // send value to hook form
              checked={value === true}
              inputRef={ref}
            />
          </label>
          <label>
            Non
            <input
              type="radio"
              onBlur={onBlur} // notify when input is touched
              onChange={() => onChange(false)} // send value to hook form
              checked={value === false}
              inputRef={ref}
            />
          </label>
        </>
      )}
    />
  );
}
```

This way, values are real booleans and zod doesn't throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

@pom421 in my case `setValueAs` function as worked as expected. The only difference I use MUI as UI framework, but it's unlikely it's the cause.

I just made a helper:

`helper.ts`

```
import { RegisterOptions } from 'react-hook-form';

export function forceHtmlRadioOutputToBeBoolean(value: string | null): boolean | null {
  if (value === 'true') {
    return true;
  } else if (value === 'false') {
    return false;
  } else if (value === null) {
    // Sometimes the radio group can be optional, allow this case
    return null;
  } else {
    throw new Error(`this radio group is supposed to only manage string boolean values ("true", "false"), or can optionally be null.`);
  }
}

export const reactHookFormBooleanRadioGroupRegisterOptions = {
  setValueAs: forceHtmlRadioOutputToBeBoolean,
} as RegisterOptions;
```

And in a random form I can:

```
                <FormControlLabel
                  value="true"
                  control={<Radio />}
                  {...register('alreadyRequestedInThePast', reactHookFormBooleanRadioGroupRegisterOptions)}
                  label="Yes, I do"
                />
```

Note that in my case MUI always converts `value={true}` into a string "true"... that's why I force the developer to manage strings on the templating side, but then, he will have a boolean in React Hook Form (and `zod` or other validating library).

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

```
const { register, handleSubmit, setValue } = useForm<Form>({ defaultValue: ... });

<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
  <input
    type="radio"
    onChange={(e) => setValue('fieldName', getRadioBooleanValue(e))
  />
</form>
```

Comment: What's `getRadioBooleanValue`?

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to change your existing structure and still want boolean values then you can use :

```js
 setValueAs: (value: string) => (value === 'true' ? true || value === 'false' : false || value),
```

in the `register` as a very tiny quick fix.

Answer (score 0):

Potential solution using `setValue` on the button to convert its type to boolean with React Hook Form :

```js
    export function forceTypeBoolean(value: string | null | boolean): boolean | null {
       return typeof value === 'boolean' ? value : value === 'true' ? true : value === 'false' ? false : null;
    }
    // use
    <button
      {...register("found", { setValueAs: forceTypeBoolean, })}
      onClick={() => setValue("found", true)}/>
```