# React-hook-forms framworks, how to make check box return true or false

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

As titled, I'm using React-hook-forms to implement some function; however, I stuck at checkbox configuration.

My goal is fairly simple, when checkbox is checked I want "active" value be set as boolean true, when check box is un-checked I want "active" value be set as boolean false. I have read through the document but still can't figure out by myself.

Here are some related code:

```
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";

  const {
    register,
    // reset,
    control,
    handleSubmit,
    setValue,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm({
    defaultValues: {
      firstname: "",
      lastname: "",
      active: false,
    },
  });
```

```
  function handleChange(event) {
    const { name, value, type, checked } = event.target;
    handleSubmit((prevFormData) => {
      return {
        ...prevFormData,
        [name]: type === "checkbox" ? checked : value,
      };
    });
  }
```

```
<Form.Group className="mb-3" controlId="formBasicCheckbox">
              <Form.Check
                name="active"
                type="checkbox"
                checked={true / false}
                label="Active"
                control={control}
                onChange={handleChange}
                {...register("active", {
                  required: false,
                })}
              />
            </Form.Group>
```

Any help or resource will be appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert values from input radio in boolean in React Hook Form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72657849/how-to-convert-values-from-input-radio-in-boolean-in-react-hook-form)

Answer (score 0):

I was just working this out myself today:

```
<Form className={styles.autoSave}>
  <Form.Check type="checkbox" label="autosave" onClick={(e) => test(e.currentTarget.checked)}/>
</Form>
```